# Setting function to call raw_input in python

Tags: python, function, raw-input

How do I make this work? I'm trying to set a global function so that I can simply call it later for raw input rather than calling the raw input where I need it.

I think I have the essence to an extent of what I need but I'm stumped as to how to format this, or if it's even possible.

Thank you in advance.

```
   def choice_1():
        choice_1 == raw_input("> ")
    def choice_1a():    
        choice_1a = raw_input("> ") 
    def choice_1b():    
        choice_1b = raw_input("> ")
```

edit: I don't think I was clear enough in the purpose of my question. Here's an update of the code I'm working on, perhaps this will clear things up.

```
print "You've arrived at your desk"


def choice_1(one):
    choice_1a = raw_input("< ")
def choice_1a():    
    choice_1a = raw_input("> ") 
def choice_1b():    
    choice_1b = raw_input("> ")

#Choice_1
print "What do you want to do?"
print "We can \n1. Read\n2. Draw\n3. Work on homework"
print choice_1
#choice 1 branch 1
if choice_1 == "1":
    print "What book should we read today?"
    print "We can read\n1. Tom Sawyer\n2. Quantum Physics \n3. Ray Bradbury"
    print choice_1a
    if choice_1a == "1":
        print "Great choice!"
    if choice_1a == "2":
        print "Heavy stuff there."
    if choice_1a == "3":
        print "Entertaining author, that one there!"
    else:
        print "Let's go to the library, maybe they'll have that one."
#choice 1 branch 2
if choice_1 == "2":
    print "What would you like to draw?"
    print "We can draw a\n1. Tiger\n2. Fish\n3. Bear "
    print choice_1b
    if choice_1b == "1":
        print "You drew a Tiger!"
    if choice_1b == "2":
        print "You drew a Fish!"
    if choice_1b == "3":
        print "You drew a Bear!"
    else:
        print "Time for some improvisation."

#choice 1 branch 3
if choice_1 == "3":
    print ""
```

does this clear some confusion?

Comment: Looks like all you are missing is some `return` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want. As @SethMMorton had noted, you had missed out on a `return`

```
def choice():
    return raw_input('> ‘)
```

By the way, this is not a nice thing to do, because, to someone reading your code, it will not be immediately clear what `choice` is doing.

I did this:

```
print 'Your name is :' + choice()
```

And it worked as expected.

**EDIT**: You should make your if statements thus:

`if choice() == "1"`:

Comment: this does not work, returns not an error code, but it's calling the function at the function, if I'm saying that right.

Comment: @Ppaisley Hm, how exactly are you calling this?

Comment: I need to be able to call the raw_input first, but thank you for the constructive comment

Comment: @Ppaisle When you write something like `choice_1a == '1' ` (as you have done) you are not comparing the **return value** of the function to 1, you are comparing the function _itself_ to 1, which is certainly not correct.

Comment: you made it work! thank you very much Rishav, you've been a great help.

I understand what you're saying about the comparison. so what was missing is telling python to _compare_ the raw_input value to the function?

Comment: I tried searching the python documentation to read about functions but I couldn't find an actual section about functions, any advice on where to read up?

Comment: @Ppaisley the documentation might be a bit _too_ harsh, but the folks at Python have written a wonderful tutorial here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @Ppaisley no problem. And I just noticed your edited comment `I understand what you're saying about the comparison. so what was missing is telling python to compare the raw_input value to the function?`. **Yes**, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def multiplier(x, y):
     ans = x * y
     print ans
```

This would be a use for a function and when ready to use it you would
  call it like this

```
 multiplier(5, 10)
      50
```

Comment: I'm trying to be able to call "choice_1" and have it ask for a raw input at that point in the code, so I can "set up" my functions at the beginning of the code, not at each point that I want them.

edit: perhaps I don't grasp the purpose of def properly??

Comment: I see alright give me ten mins let me see what i can come up with

Comment: Er This takes two lines of input, and returns the second one. This isn’t correct, I’m afraid.

Comment: we create functions so we don't have to keep writing the same code i don't think its that u don't understand def or writing functions.

Comment: I don't think I'm grasping what he is trying to do entirely

Comment: No, no @James what I mean is that, when I call your choice function, is that it will input _two_ lines (you are calling `raw_input()` twice) and you are not saving the first line into a variable.

Comment: So, it will input 2 lines from the user, but to the programmer, it will return only the second line. (Try it out and see)

Comment: rite so all its really doing is displaying what was entered and thats all. yea your rite so if we gave it an object that he could call later and check the choice that would help.

Comment: check the update to my question that I made, I included more of my code so you have an example of what I'm trying to do

Comment: yea your not to clear on functions they can't be called like that first of all you should just add your raw_input() functions where need be its pretty much the same thing.

Comment: okay I thought I might not be clear enough. Thank you for the time, I'll try to expand my knowledge.

Comment: @James you may also return the value :)

Comment: yes you are correct lol thats why i love Python so many styles and ways to write the code its wonderful.